# TA-lib: SMA and EMA values are coming out equal for all periods

Tags: ta-lib

When I calculate the SMA and EMA values using TA-lib for any period, the values are always equal. Does anyone else has any experience on this? Thanks.

Code for Ema (I just replace Core.Ema with Core.Sma for SMA):

```
            double[] output = new double[closePrices.Length];
            int begin;
            int length;

            Core.RetCode retCode = Core.Ema(closePrices.Length - 1, closePrices.Length - 1, closePrices, period, out begin, out length, output);

            if (retCode == Core.RetCode.Success)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    result = Math.Round(output[i], 5);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nope. It should work. Please provide us with the code sample.

Comment: Hi truf. I've added the code to my original post. Thx.

Comment: Would be great to get also a sample of the data to reproduce the problem. What are your `period` value? Are you sure that values are equal if `Math.Round` is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Your starting index and ending index for the EMA method is the same. Change the  starting index to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate EMA at time period 20, you need at least 21 data points for that